# Dienstagnachmittag oder Dienstag Nachmittag

Tags: compound

Wann schreibt man Wochentag und Zeitangabe zusammen, wann nicht? Wann schreibt man z.B. "Montagvormittag" und wann "Montag Vormittag"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ich würde es immer zusammenschreiben.**

Es handelt sich um eine Formsache. Dem Verständnis schaden beide Varianten nicht. Bei Deutschprüfungen wurde bei mir die getrennte Schreibweise als leichter Fehler gewertet.

> Verbindungen aus Wochentag und Tageszeitangabe werden meist
> zusammengeschrieben

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dienstag

Weitere Beispiele:
https://www.pcs-campus.de/praxis/texten/wochentage/

Answer (score 1):

Die zugrundeliegende Regel ist [§37 (1.1) der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6155#par37-1-1)

> § 37
> Substantive, Adjektive, Verbstämme, Pronomen oder Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen. [...]
>
> (1) Zusammensetzungen:
> (1.1) mit substantivischem Erstglied:
> Holztür, Hoheitsgebiet, Holzbearbeitung, Hosenrock

Da sowohl "Dienstag" als auch "Vormittag" Substantive sind, greift diese Regel hier. Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, schreibt man allerdings erst seit der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 "Dienstagvormittag", daher ist die Verwendung in der Praxis sicher uneinheitlich. [Bei Google Ngrams kann man seit Mitte der 90er einen starken Anstieg von "Dienstagvormittag" erkennen, bei gleichzeitiger Abnahme von "Dienstag vormittag".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dienstagvormittag%2CDienstag+vormittag&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#)